# Calculation speed difference of Great Sage vs Raphael vs Ciel

Tags: reincarnated-as-a-slime

How much faster is Raphael's calculation speed vs Great Sage? If Rimuru's mind acceleration went from 1,000x to 1,000,000x upon evolving, would Raphael also be 1000x faster than Great Sage? How much faster would Ciel have been over Raphael?